# Ldap Size limit exceeded while using Simple Paged Results

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, ldap, limit

I am trying to get all users from an LDAP server, using PHP 7.4 and Symfonys [Ldap Component](https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/components/ldap.html) (Version 5.3). We have a ldap server size limit for a single request of 500 users but there are more than 500 users on the server.

To overcome the size limit, I am using [Simple Paged Results](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2696.html) with a page size of 100, but I still only get 500 users back in total when trying to fetch the users. After the size limit 500 is reached, the provided cookie which usually is sent back by the ldap server to control paging is empty and I get the error `Size limit exceeded`.

Simple paged result control is handled by the Symfony Ldap Component. The code executed (which is calling the native PHP functions for ldap requests) can be found [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.3/src/Symfony/Component/Ldap/Adapter/ExtLdap/Query.php#L79).

I call this function with the following parameters:

```
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapInterface;

...

private LdapInterface $ldap;

...


$this->ldap->bind($this->searchDn, $this->searchPassword);
$query = $this->ldap->query(
    $this->dnString,
    'query',
    [
        'filter' => [
            '*',
            'entryUUID',
            'modifyTimestamp',
        ],
        'pageSize' => 100
    ]
);
$users = $query->execute();

...
```

I also tried the same using PHP 8.1 and Symfony 5.4 but the problem persist.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Increasing the server size request limit is not an option since it would only delay but not fix the problem.